# Accessing Devices on a VPN's Subnet from the Server's Local Network

Tags: networking, vpn, wireguard

I ***want*** to be able to SSH, remote desktop, ping, etc. to remote clients that have connected to my VPN/Pi from any device on my main network - *WITHOUT having to VPN inside my own network to that server*. In best case, I would identify that "main network" as `eth0` and/or `wlan0` so that whatever network the pi is connected to, it works.

I think I need a new route or iptable, but I am unsure. My home network runs on `192.168.1.x` and my Wireguard VPN is on `10.0.0.x` so no subnet overlap.

I am running Wireguard at home on a Raspberry Pi. I can connect home and to my home network remotely very well.

I can *make* it work by:

1. Update pi's `wg0.conf` to include under the relevant "remote client" `[PEER]` the line `AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.8/32, 192.168.1.0` (*side note, I am unsure why `192.168.1.0/24` crashes on wg0 restart?*)
2. Change the client wireguard conf on my computer (in my network) to have under `[Peer]`, `Endpoint = 192.168.1.pi:51900`
3. Activate Wireguard on my internal computer (natively on `192.168.1.laptop`) and thus have an IP on the VPN
4. SSH, ping, remote desktop to the "remote client" then works

My `wg0.conf` includes:

```
[Interface]
...
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
...
```

Comment: Right, but what's the question, if you can already make it work?

Comment: @u1686_grawity Thanks. I want to do it WITHOUT having to VPN inside my own network to that server/pi